# nginxでモジュールを作成して商用に売ることは可能ですか？

Tags: nginx

やりたいことは以下です。

・nginxのモジュールを開発する
・リクエストをフックして商用に必要な処理を行う
・ビルドしたnginxを売る

知りたい事は以下です。

・ライセンス的な問題。
・ソースコードを明示する必要があるか？

Answer (score 1):

ちゃんと調べていないので、少し自信はないですが・・・。

ウィキペディアによると、nginxはBSDライクライセンスとのことなので、
ライセンス的には問題ないと思います。
また、BSDライセンスの特性上、ソースコードの開示も不要だと思われます。

GPLであれば、派生のソースコードの開示は義務付けられますが、
BSDですので大丈夫だと思います。
※自信がないのはこの点です。

ただし、著作権表記およびライセンス表記が再頒布時には必須ですのでこの点は注意が必要です。